# Share formatting rules between netbeans and eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, code-formatting

What is the best way to have a common code (java) formatting when using both Netbeans and Eclipse in a project? I have been searching for a solution but cannot find anything really suitable. I came accross jalopy as a maven plugin but I'm looking for something which is free.

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956900/code-cleanup-in-netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Maven you might want to have a look at the [Checkstyle plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/). It's integrated with the Netbeans project settings and you have editor support. I don't know about the quality of Eclipse integration, but at least you can enforce the rules you like.

Comment: Yes I had a look at checkstyle and it looks promising. Is it also possible to "apply" the rules so the developers don't have to do manual format corrections? What I could see it will only give warnings?

Comment: When editing a source file, hitting "ALT+SHIFT + F" (aka "Format") will re-format your code according to the CheckStyle rules, including adding missing braces and newlines and whatnot. I'm not aware of a method to apply the rules to a full tree of source files, though.

Comment: Ok thanks, formatting per file will be good enough so it answers my question.

Comment: Hi, Can you share the checkstyle rules file you used to keep NetBeans and Eclispe the same.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [Eclipse Code Formatter plugin](https://github.com/markiewb/eclipsecodeformatter_for_netbeans) for Netbeans for Java files. We have defined formatting rules in Eclipse.