# Sax Parser No method found to parse

Tags: java, sax, saxparser, saxparseexception

Tried to run the code mentioned in the following [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-example.html)
Everything compiles perfectly but it shows the error in the main method.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;


public class SaxParserExample {

public static void main (String argv []) {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        InputStream    xmlInput  =
            new FileInputStream("data\\sax-example.xml");

        SAXParser      saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        SaxHandler handler   = new SaxHandler();
        saxParser.parse(xmlInput, handler);

        for(Driver driver : handler.drivers){
            System.out.println(driver);
        }
    } catch (Throwable err) {
        err.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

}

on the following line:

```
saxParser.parse(xmlInput, handler);
```

Error:

```
error: no suitable method found for parse(InputStream,SaxHandler)
            saxParser.parse(xmlInput, handler);
    method SAXParser.parse(InputStream,HandlerBase) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; SaxHandler cannot be converted to HandlerBase)
    method SAXParser.parse(InputStream,DefaultHandler) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; SaxHandler cannot be converted to DefaultHandler)
    method SAXParser.parse(String,HandlerBase) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; InputStream cannot be converted to String)
    method SAXParser.parse(String,DefaultHandler) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; InputStream cannot be converted to String)
    method SAXParser.parse(File,HandlerBase) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; InputStream cannot be converted to File)
    method SAXParser.parse(File,DefaultHandler) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; InputStream cannot be converted to File)
    method SAXParser.parse(InputSource,HandlerBase) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; InputStream cannot be converted to InputSource)
    method SAXParser.parse(InputSource,DefaultHandler) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; InputStream cannot be converted to InputSource)
```

As you can see I have already included necessary files yet it doesn't compile.

Comment: Can you show us your `SaxHandler` implementation?

Comment: You can find it in the following link:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-example.html
 it's the same,

Comment: I'd be worried about `jdk.internal.org.xml.sax`...

Comment: I think you actually want `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser`

Comment: Are you developing without an IDE? Half of these dependencies are unused. Also, copying form the tutorial works for me, so you must have done something differently.

Comment: Yep - I think your IDE has auto-imported the wrong class(es) for `SAXException` and/or `DefaultHandler`

Comment: I'm using Netbeans IDE, my IDE imported the classes automatically, should I copy the imports from the websites and try ?

Comment: @Deltharis Could you please tell which IDE you are using

Comment: IntelliJ at the moment, though any IDE should work - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956900/code-cleanup-in-netbeans for Netbeans. Also, yes, if you imported the dependencies manually (especially for your `SaxHandler` implementation which seems to be the problem) you should try to revert to the ones in the tutorial, you might have gotten the wrong classes there.

Comment: Waaaait a second. Did you put everything from the tutorial into a single file? Is that why Netbeans put those dependencies there? In that case @MadProgrammer was correct in his (now deleted) answer

Comment: No, I made 4 classes, driver.java, veichle.java, SaxHandler.java, SaxParserExample.java

Comment: Do you have the libraries of a parser implementation (i.e. Xerces, Saxon, ....) correctly set in your classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the imports from

```
import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
```

to

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
```

solves the error