# How do I change method code formating in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I installed new NetBeans 8.1, and when i want to format code by Alt+Shift+F my code placed in method looks very ugly, like there:

[image]

How can I change that code formating to that like i had before in NetBeans 7.4 and on the image there:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956900/code-cleanup-in-netbeans

Comment: that is no that I tried also to import settings from my 7.4 NB and that not helped, and I tried also from 8.1 from my friend(He have normal formating like I want to have too) and that no helps too, that must be somewhere else, probably not in tools>options

Answer (score 1):

You can format **multiple files/folders** at a time! 
In the `Projects` window/sidebar, if you select one or more folders or files and press `Alt`+`Shift`+`F`.

NetBeans asks *"Recursively format selected files and folders?"*

and pressing OK will recursively format all the selected files/folders.

On Mac OS X, shortcut is `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`. (note: it's `Ctrl` and not `⌘`)

**EDIT :-**

**Open Tools -> Options -> Keymap**, then look for the action called ***"Re-indent current line or selection"*** and set whatever shortcut you want. It will work.

[image]

Comment: Ok, that works good for methods with "single arguent", but I mean what to do with that white spaces "indent" which i marked by red arrows, tocan change that indent in methods where I use couple of objects, as argument(like on images I added in topic).

Comment: Ok, thank you that is what I mean, but maybe you know any way to do that same not to current line, or selection, but anywhere I click that do that for all file?